# Inserting a string into a bytebuffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I am trying to write a bunch of integers and a string into the byte buffer. Later this byte array will be written to the hard drive. Everything seems to be fine except when I am writing the string in the loop only the last character is written. The parsing of the string appears correct as I have checked that. 
It appears to be the way I use the bbuf.put statement. Do I need to flush it after, and why does the .putInt statement work fine and not .put

```
//write the PCB from memory to file system
private static void _tfs_write_pcb()
{

    int c;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[11];


    //to get the bytes from volume name
    try {
        bytes = constants.filename.getBytes("UTF-8");           //convert to bytes format to pass to function
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bl_size);

    bbuf = bbuf.putInt(rt_dir_start);
    bbuf = bbuf.putInt(first_free_data_bl);
    bbuf = bbuf.putInt(num_bl_fat);
    bbuf = bbuf.putInt(bl_size);
    bbuf = bbuf.putInt(max_rt_entries);
    bbuf = bbuf.putInt(ft_copies);


    for (c=0; c < vl_name.length(); c++) {
        System.out.println((char)bytes[c]);
        bbuf = bbuf.put(bytes[c]);
    }

    _tfs_write_block(1, bbuf.array());

}
```

Comment: Two questions - 1) Your loop max is `vl_name.length` rather than `bytes.length`. Is this intentional? If so, what are you trying to accomplish? 2) Have you considered just using `bbuf.put( bytes )` or `bbuf.put(bytes,offset,length)`?

Comment: yes its intentional. They are both the same size so it doesn't matter. I've change the code to bbuf = bbuf.put(bytes); as you suggested but the exact same thing happens

Comment: Have you examined the value of `constants.filename` in a debugger or a debug print? Are you sure that `blSize` is large enough to hold the six 4-byte integers and the string?

Comment: yes thanks. its only 3 characters in the string "TFS" also bl_size is 128 bytes and I have used it before in other writes with no issues. new to bytebuffer but this is stumping me.

Comment: is there a way to print out the byte buffer array on screen to see whats going on easily. don't want to rewrite the tostring method to see the output

Comment: p.s. I am also using 8 bit characters in the string. shouldnt be an issue as I used them in other places with no issues. my understanding is the byte array won't care its just a set of bytes

Comment: I'm presuming from the value "TFS" you show that none of the 8-bit characters are in the range 128-255. How are you creating the string from the 8-bit characters? Yes, you could make a String from the contents of the ByteBuffer, using `ByteBuffer.get( byte, offset, length )` and a charset. By the way, as of Java 7 you can use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead of requiring the runtime parsing of "UTF-8".

Comment: Thanks. yes all looks good I actually printed the array before the bytebuffer it looks great. for (c=0; c<3; c++) {
   System.out.println((char)bytes[c]);
  }
  bbuf = bbuf.put(bytes);

Comment: Needs a full [MCVE].

Comment: Here is an example MCVE based on your code: http://pastebin.com/DbDaw6Gk - however, it works exactly as it should. This strongly indicates that the problem is not in the code that you posted, and demonstrates why you need to develop an MCVE before you post a question.

Comment: SOLVED! by carefully going through the byte buffer I see that everything was shifted two bytes. I am using 8 bit ascii characters. So I put bbuf =bbuf.putShort(x); and this works great. Thank you everyone for your time it is much appreciated. I learned so much. Again thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ByteBuffer has a method for put'ting an array of byte.  Is there a reason to put them one at a time?  I note that put(byte) is abstract as well.

So the `for` loop is simplified to:

```
bbuf = bbuf.put(bytes, 6, bytes.length);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put-byte:A-

**EDIT:** The Javadoc specifies that put(byte[]) begins at index 0, so use the form put(byte[], index, length) instead.

```
public final ByteBuffer put(byte[] src)

Relative bulk put method  (optional operation).

This method transfers the entire content of the given source byte array
into this buffer. An invocation of this method of the form dst.put(a) 
behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation

     dst.put(a, 0, a.length)
```

Of course, it really should not matter HOW you insert the String bytes.  I am just suggesting discovery experimentation.

Comment: The method `put(byte)` is not abstract in the subclass of ByteBuffer returned by `ByteBuffer.allocate()`.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the code but it still doesn't work. Exact same result only writes the last character bbuf = bbuf.put(bytes);

Comment: Have you walked through this code in a step debugger to see exactly what is happening?  Sometimes there is no substitute for watching what is actually being done.

Comment: good idea. I just did and it clearly is not inserting the string into the byte buffer. the bytes array has value 84/70/83 TFS but the bytebuffer does not have it. I even tried putting it in absolute form with different indexes. The debugger gave me this. 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -128, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...... 0's for the rest

Comment: SOLVED! by carefully going through the byte buffer I see that everything was shifted two bytes. I am using 8 bit ascii characters. So I put bbuf =bbuf.putShort(x); and this works great. Thank you everyone for your time it is much appreciated. I learned so much. Again thanks